# How to hide p1 within div

Tags: css

How can I remove only one paragraph (p1) from a div? This is my complete html and css: http://jsfiddle.net/8Q3YH/

I want to remove p1 completely from the below.

```
<div id="quickSummary">
        <p class="p1"><span>A demonstration of what can be accomplished       visually through <acronym title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</acronym>-based design. Select any style sheet from the list to load it into this page.</span></p>
        <p class="p2"><span>Download the sample <a href="zengarden-sample.html" title="This page's source HTML code, not to be modified.">html file</a> and <a href="zengarden-sample.css" title="This page's sample CSS, the file you may modify.">css file</a></span></p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with CSS you would do

```
#quickSummary .p1 { display:none; }
```

This hides the element with the class p1

you could use a pseudo class but it is not supported by all browsers yet

that would be

```
#quickSummary p:first-child { display:none; }
```

Which means, the first paragraph tag inside quickSummary will be hidden.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks very much! I thought it was #quickSummary p1 or p1 span.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
#quickSummary .p1 {display: none;} //This will empty the space on your web page

#quickSummary .p1 {visibility: hidden;} //This will hide the paragraph but will reserve the space
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this css class on your page

```
.p1{display:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#quickSummary .p1{display:none; }   // to hide the element
```

From **CSS you can only hide the element** (not visible on the browser ). **To remove it completely from the DOM you can use jQuery**

```
$('#quickSummary').find(".p1").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS?

```
.p1 {
display:none;
}
```

Also; it's not required to paste your entire page into JsFiddle - you only need paste the bits of markup that you're having a problem with.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your need.

using CSS

```
div#quickSummary .p1
{
display:none;
}
```

using jQuery

```
$('div#quickSummary .p1').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many options in CSS like

```
display:block;      (or)  /* text is absent */
visibility:hidden;  (or)  /* text is present but in hidden state */
color:transparent;  /* text is present but in hidden state */
```

EXAMPLE :

```
.p1, .p1>a {color:transparent;}
```

Or else use jquery to remove the `p` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try CSS3 pseudo selectors - that way you will not need classes. Beware though does not work in older browsers.

Try

```
#quickSummary li:first-of-type{
display:none; visibility:hidden;
}
```